# My work has been done today or my work was done today?

Tags: tense

My concern is if I m using present perfect tense to 'today ' time will be used or not ? If not so will we use past tense

Comment: Why are you using a passive construction? *I have done my work* is probably more natural, and you could explicitly specify the timeframe with *I have done my work today*  or *I have done today's work* if that's important but not contextually obvious.

Comment: Neither sounds particularly natural. You might say "My work is done for the day" if you have completed all the tasks you set out to do.

Comment: I agree it's not very natural as stated, but "My work was done by somebody else today" or "My work has been done by somebody else today" are both possible. Which you use depends on the usual rules for choosing between simple past and perfect, which I can't choose between without more context.

Comment: I have finished work for today.

Comment: Your question doesn’t have **an** answer until you provide more context, more detail. For instance, besides all the other sentences already offered, **if** you mean that there remains no more work to be done today, then you could say, “My work **is** done **for** today.”